# Seg fault involving a struct and array together but not separately

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program for my research that requires a non-trivial indexing scheme to deal with a spin ice system. To help with the indexing I use a combination of structs and arrays. Every struct holds the 16 points contained within a cubic cell [I tried to post a picture of the cubic cell but stackoverflow said I needed at least 10 reputation points to do so, my apologies], however for numerical reasons later these need to be store in one matrix.

The values that determine the size of the system (i.e. how big the simulation cube is) work fine for L=1, L=2, L=3. However when I try L=4 I have a seg fault. The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
/* The indexing of this program is as 
 *  (i,j,k) refers to which cubic cell you are in 
 *  (l,m) refers to which particle in the cubic cell you are in 
 *  the order is as follows
 *  (l,m) = (1,1) (1,3)   (3,1) (3,3)
 *          (1,0) (1,2)   (3,0) (3,2)
 * 
 *          (0,1) (0,3)   (2,1) (2,3)
 *          (0,0) (0,2)   (2,0) (2,2)
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define FOR_IJKLM for (i=0; i<L; i++) \
                    for (j=0; j<L; j++) \
                      for (k=0; k<L; k++) \
                        for (l=0; l<4; l++) \
                          for (m=0; m<4; m++)

// L  := integer length of convential cubic cell
// Np := Number of total particles in the system
#define L   4
#define Np  16*L*L*L

struct ConventialCube{
  double p[4][4][3];   // Position of particle 
  double mu[4][4][3];  // Magnetic Moment of particle
};

void initialize(struct ConventialCube cc[][L][L]);

int main(void){
  struct ConventialCube cc[L][L][L]; 
    initialize(cc); 

  double ewaldMatrix[Np][Np];

  return 0;
}

void initialize(struct ConventialCube cc[][L][L]){
  int i, j, k, l, m, d;
  double s = 1.0/sqrt(3);

  double sv[4][3] = {
    {-s,-s,-s},
    {-s, s, s},
    { s,-s, s},
    { s, s,-s}
  };
  double O[4][3] = {
    {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {0.0, 0.5, 0.5},
    {0.5, 0.0, 0.5},
    {0.5, 0.5, 0.0}
  };

  FOR_IJKLM{
    double CO[] = {i,j,k};
    for (d=0; d<3; d++){
      cc[i][j][k].mu[l][m][d] = sv[m][d];
      cc[i][j][k].p[l][m][d] = CO[d] + O[l][d] + O[m][d]/2.0;
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned before the code runs for L=1, L=2, L=3, however at L=4 it breaks. Some peculiarities I have found are the following:

- commenting out the ewaldMatrix array will allow L=4 to run
- changing the ewaldMatrix to an integer type will allow L=4 to run
- commenting out initialize(cc) line will allow the code to run
- writing Np with just one less data point will allow it to run (i.e. defining Np as 
  16*L*L*L-1)

I would greatly appreciate any input or advice as the L=4 case is absolutely necessary (I don't actually need anything higher than L=4 just L=4 - Murphy's Law I guess).

Comment: Where does it crash ?

Comment: If you post a link to your image I'll put it in the question for you.

Comment: Well, what does your debugger say?

Comment: I am not sure, if I comment out the matrix and leave the struct in it will run. If I comment out the struct and leave the matrix in it will run.

Comment: Why do you switch between `L` and literal `4`?

Comment: Thank you LightnessRaces,the picture isn't necessary but it may help when people question why I am structuring the data the way it is
http://www.sciencemag.org/content/294/5546/1495/F5.large.jpg

Comment: The variable `double ewaldMatrix[Np][Np];` in `main` is too large for a local variable, this  ends up in a stack overflow here. Anyway its not used.

Comment: defining L as 4 allows me to pass arrays easier. I am used to Fortran 95 as my strongest language and this helps me emulate some of the numerics I did in it.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelWalz if I define it outside Main the code compiles. I would not of thought of that for days and am amaze my question was answered so quickly. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overflowing the stack. Declare your two arrays as static:

```
int main(void){
    static struct ConventialCube cc[L][L][L]; 
    initialize(cc); 

    static double ewaldMatrix[Np][Np];
    return 0;
}
```

or as globals:

```
static struct ConventialCube cc[L][L][L]; 
static double ewaldMatrix[Np][Np];

int main(void){
    initialize(cc); 
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also declare these objects on the heap using `malloc()`.